# Using Python Regular expression how to store filter variables

Tags: python

I want to take out two variables from file `ss.txt`. Using regular expression I filter out two variables `[('TC-01 ', 'Passed')]` but I don't know how to store and print those two variables. I have attached the regular expression code - please view it and give your valuable reply.

**Program:**

```
import r
f = open('ss.txt', 'r')
for line in f:
    m = re.findall("(TC-01\s)(P\w+)", line)
print m
```

Answer (score 0):

`re.findall` should return a list of tuples of the matched patterns, in your case m could be like this

```
[('firstmatch', 'secondmatch'), ('anotherfirstmatch', 'anothersecondmatch')...]
```

So this is how you print it:

```
import re
f = open('ss.txt', 'r')
for line in f:
    m = re.findall("(TC-01\s)(P\w+)", line)
    for match in m:
      print match[0], match[1]
```